# Remove header and footer in html to print page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way to remove header and footer of a html page, so that if user print it, there is no header and footer.

User can choose to remove it using print setup, but i wondering is there any css or javascript to remove it programatically?

thank you for any response.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. If you find this out, let us know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like:

```
   @media print
   {
      .noprint { display: none; }
   }
```

Now you can apply the `noprint` class to element you want to hide in printing.

Comment: This class name sounds a bit too much like `.bold-red` to me. I see hiding from the printer as more of a presentational thing than a semantical thing.

Comment: Add this to your header or div tag that wraps the content you want to hide: `<header class="noprint">`

Answer (score 4):

I do some googling and everybody said: "Can't remove them!" except using ActiveX and 3rd party plugins.

I wonder why some reporting controls (Telerik Reporting, DevX,...) can hide Header & Footer without using ActiveX or plugins! Are they print the page in another ways? What way?

Comment: Telerik is generating a PDF server side and setting iframe src=PDF_URL.  The PDF itself has a javascript print command embeded in it, which triggers the browser print dialog.

Comment: Correction: it triggers the PDF plugin print dialog, not the browser print dialog.  That is how they avoid those pesky browser headers.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be referring to the header and footer lines that the browser is adding and not contents of the printed page. In that case the answer is: No, you can only change it in the settings.