# javascript print action - printing date/ url

Tags: javascript, html, printing

In one of my project, I need to display print option to the user (on loading html page).

While this works fine, but the content printed contains the 
url and date of printing.

Please let me know how I can configure at javascript level (not at printer level) so that these default things (url, date of printing, page 1 of 10 etc..) are not printed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849926/remove-header-and-footer-in-html-to-print-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately date, file path are added by the browser and you can not control them with javascript, the only option is the browser itself.