# How to print html without the additions of browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I want to print a page of html, every browser add the url and title of the website in the very top or in very bottom of the page. 
How can I print the html page only just what I see.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox for example when you try to preview it you can click on "Page Setup"-> the second tab is header/footer, there you can choose what to be displayed in the very top or the very bottom of the printed page, if you choose blank in all fields the footer and header will be cleared of all data and you can print only what you see :)

You can also try the suggested solutions in the topics below:

[Remove the default browser header and footer when printing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255534/remove-the-default-browser-header-and-footer-when-printing-html)

[Can I remove the URL from my print css, so the web address doesn't print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192806/can-i-remove-the-url-from-my-print-css-so-the-web-address-doesnt-print)

[Remove the default browser header and footer when printing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255534/remove-the-default-browser-header-and-footer-when-printing-html)

[Disabling browser print options (headers, footers, margins) from page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960939/disabling-browser-print-options-headers-footers-margins-from-page)

[Remove header and footer in html to print page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849926/remove-header-and-footer-in-html-to-print-page)

I hope they are useful :)

Comment: Thanks, so can I do that by coding not from the browser?

Comment: It seems no standard solution for that :). Thanks after all